# copy the contents of an array to another and deleting the contents of the old array

Tags: java, android, arrays, copy

I am trying to copy the contents of an array to another array after a button is clicked. I want the oldArray to be cleared of the previous data after it is copied to newArray. I have this code and I'm lost. can anyone please guide me on how to do this? here's what I have so far.

```
    final String [] oldArray;

    oldArray = new String[5];
    oldArray[0] = "c";
    oldArray[1] = "h";
    oldArray[2] = "a";
    oldArray[3] = "r";
    oldArray[4] = "m";

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);

        {
            oldarrayOut.setText(oldArray[i]);
        }

    bOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            String[] newArray = new String[5];

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
                {
                    newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
                    newarrayOut.setText(newArray[i]);
                }



        }
    });
```

please feel free to notify me also if there's something wrong in my code. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are few in-built methods as well as libraries to copy contents of an array. May be you can try to use that. Please check Collection Framework and also search for libraries on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
                       ^-- here
```

Which transforms the for loop into a loop doing nothing at each iteration. Remove it.

To clear the old array, simply use

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    oldArray[i] = null;
    newarrayOut.setText(newArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for pointing that out. Maybe that's the reason why I get errors. Your answer is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
oldArray = new String[5];
```

or

```
oldArray = null;
```

So the old array wont point to the really old array, but to a new one.

The first one is better if you know you're gonna use it again, and you know the length of the array. The other need to be treated safe as it may cause NPE if you access it.

Comment: That doesn't clear the array. If some other object has a reference to the old array, it still sees the old values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the oldarrayOut and newarrayOut fields are doing, but it seems like putting

```
oldArray = null;
```

outside the for loop in your onClick method would do it.

You seem to be copying the array successfully, just not initializing oldArray once you've finished copying.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] newArray = (String[]) oldArray.clone();
```

copy the contents of an array to another.
Try this to copy oldArray to newArray.

```
Arrays.fill( oldArray, null );
```

deleting the contents of the old array